# A big mess with Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I have this structure for a site: **home/Projects/Site_name**

For an unknown reason I can't access the links: **Site_name/page1/**, so I want to make an **index.php** permalink and hope it will fix the problem.

Trying to access wp-admin will not work for me in order to change directly from there. When I create the following htaccess file the links are the same ( **Site_name/page1/** ):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Projects/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Projects/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Normally after this htaccess the links should be **Site_name/index.php/page1/**  but they aren't.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong because I ran out of options here?